# Using Appcache with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, offline, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

Been trying to make Appcache works with CI for several hours but still couldn't get it work.

Background:

I'm using IIS server. I've tested the Appcache by putting the manifest file and the php file that needs to be cached in a simple folder, it worked, so I'm pretty sure the server environment is good.

Say I want to cache the url below

http://mydomain.com.au/myapp/index.php/test/index

Here's my manifest.php (I don't know which one will work so I put 2 lines under CACHE, they all refer to the same view file)

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/cache-manifest');
    echo "CACHE MANIFEST

    CACHE:
    index.php
    http://mydomain.com.au/myapp/index.php/test/index
    ";
?>
```

Below is my view file(index.php) placed in the view folder of course

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="manifest.php">
  <body>
    this is a test
  </body>
</html>
```

Question is, where should I put this manifest file? And what file I should list under CACHE? Is there any routine that I need to follow if I want to use appcache with CI?

I've tried putting it in the same view folder, in a public folder(outside of application folder) with no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To those trigger happy editors, Appcache !== Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `Manifest` controller with just an `index()` method, and make `/index.php/manifest` return the `CACHE MANIFEST` document (with appropriate headers).

And then include that on the page with

```
<html manifest="/myapp/index.php/manifest">
```

---

Additional notes:

- app cache works with urls, not files — so it has no idea that index.php and index.php/index (etc) are "the same file".
- if a html file includes a manifest, that file is cached automatically, so you don't have to explicitly include that in the CACHE: directive. (You only need to explicitly list additional css/js files, etc)
- in the manifest, don't use the full URL (*http://…*), just the path itself (*/myapp/index…*).
- I highly reccomend you go through the Application Cache documentation once again just to make sure you've understood everything correctly. It's a really tricky thing to get working correctly.

Comment: Very thorough answer. Before I saw your answer I've given up any hopes that I can do it in CI, so I created a HTML/JS only application that only use ajax to grab the data and js to render the page hehe...Could've avoided the trouble of writing 5000 lines of js code to realise something relatively simple if done in PHP. Will do it your way for my next project. Thanks a lot!