# Codeigniter and appcache: Failed to parse manifest

Tags: codeigniter, html5-appcache

I've been stuck on this for a few days and i ran out of google-fu now so lets go over my implementation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="index.php/Appcache/">
```

Handled with a manifest controller as specified in this stackoverflow page :
[Using Appcache with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087780/using-appcache-with-codeigniter)

The manifest

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/cache-manifest");
echo"CACHE MANIFEST:

# v 0.1.3

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
/ Offline.html";
?>
```

When i load the html page the link to the manifest works I'm not getting a fetching error but a parsing error : Application Cache Error event: Failed to parse manifest .
i have cleared cache, tried multiple browsers safari (gives a similar error) and Firefox (just gives no error at all )

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a semicolon after your echo statement in the manifest.

Comment: Oops a bad copy and past caused that thank you for the observation .
it didn't solve the parsing error thou .

Comment: Have you tried adding the slash "/" before Offline.html as well, so your fallback would be "/ /Offline.html" ? (setting the path to be absolute)

Comment: also try setting "index.php/Appcache/" will  to be absolute also "/index.php/Appcache/" also.

Comment: I have tried both requested suggestions adding the absolute path to "/index.php/Appcache/ and Setting the / /Offline.html still gives me the parsing error thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

the problem was fairly simple CACHE MANIFEST: it should be without the :